# How to bind dropdownlist in razor pages for modelstate validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this form built using Razor Pages in C#. The is the code for create.cshtml. It has a dropdown list.

```
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="MetaDropdown.Id" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="MetaDropdown.Id" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="MetaDropdown.Id" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="MetaDropdown.MetaFieldId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="MetaDropdown.MetaFieldId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.MetaFieldId"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="MetaDropdown.Value" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="MetaDropdown.Value" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="MetaDropdown.Value" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="MetaDropdown.active" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MetaDropdown.active)
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the code behind.

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public CreateModel(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        ViewData["MetaFieldId"] = new SelectList(_context.meta_fields, "Id", "FieldName");
        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public MetaDropdown MetaDropdown { get; set; }
    

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.meta_dropdowns.Add(MetaDropdown);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

The issue is when I submit the form, its `ModelState.IsValid` is false. Upon checking, the error is due to `MetaField` field is missing. I think this is due to the way I bind the dropdownlist.

[image]

[image]

This is `MetaDropdown` model

```
public class MetaDropdown
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int MetaFieldId { get; set; }

    public string? Value { get; set; }
    
    public bool active { get; set; }

    public virtual MetaField MetaField { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any input for the _MetaField_ in the cshtml, so you couldn't expect this field to get any value when the model is sent back to the post method.

Comment: Does the `MetaField` is a model type property which is not declared with `[Required]`?

Comment: Actually `MetaField` is just the navigation property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `.NET 6`/`.NET 7`.  From .NET 6 the **non-nullable property must be required**, otherwise the ModelState will be invalid.

To achieve your requirement, **the first way** is you can remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your project file(double-click the project name or right-click the project to choose Edit Project File).

**The second way**, you can add `?` to allow nullable:

```
public class MetaDropdown 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //other properties....
    public virtual MetaField? MetaField{ get; set; }  //change here...
}
```

**The third way**, you can initialize the model like below:

```
public class MetaDropdown 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //other properties....
    public virtual MetaField MetaField{ get; set; } = new MetaField(); //change here...
}
```